# Webservice return 401 when i try to access from my c# code

Tags: c#, web-services, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

In my webservice working fine in my postman. But not working when i try from my c# code.

```
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                webrequest.Method = "GET";
                webrequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxx==");
                webrequest.Headers.Add("Username", "zzz");
                webrequest.Headers.Add("Password", "aaaa");
                HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
                Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
                string result = string.Empty;
                result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                webresponse.Close();
```

It always return 401 unauthorised. How can i fix this issue.

Comment: what happens when you debug and step through it? What errors do you get?

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: Are you call the C# code from the same machine/IP address as Postman is installed ?

Comment: Yes same machine

Comment: so the service your calling isnt in your network \ on your machine for you to be able to access? If postman is on the same machine are you 100% certain your sending the same information

Comment: In Basic (sure?) authentication, the Username and Password in the Header should be Base64 encoded. You can also use the WebRequest `Credentials` property:  `httpRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;`
`httpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[USR]", "[PWD]");`. You could even use both at the same time. The encoding for the Header is like: `"Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[USR]" + ":" + "[PWD]")`